# helcim.js return Invalid merchant id error

Tags: php, laravel, payment-gateway

I am integrating Helcim payment gateway in my project using helcim.js for tokenization of card, but I am getting invalid merchant id error.

This is the code snippets, I took from helcim doc,

@csrf

```
<!--SETTINGS-->
<input type="hidden" id="token" value="sdfsdfsdf435646"> //this is  dummy  i am using original here
<input type="hidden" id="language" value="en">
<input type="hidden" id="test" value="1">


<!--CARD-INFORMATION-->
Card Token: <input type="text" id="cardToken" value="1"><br/>
Credit Card Number: <input type="text" id="cardNumber" value="4124939999999990"><br/>
Expiry Month: <input type="text" id="cardExpiryMonth" value="01"> Expiry Year: <input type="text" id="cardExpiryYear" value="05"><br/>
CVV: <input type="text" id="cardCVV" value="100"><br/>
```

I have read the whole document, but did not find any solution.

Comment: I'd start by checking if your config settings match the environment, especially regarding the transaction settings - https://devdocs.helcim.com/docs/creating-a-new-config#transaction-settings Having "test mode" and "currency" correct, is probably quite essential.

Comment: i`ve checked currency and test mode .

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="test" value="1"> this is the input field for test mode

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was account setting issue . i contacted helcim support at cfenwick@helcim.com and they resolve the issue.